# XSLT 2.0 How to tokenize values of multiple elements and correlate them together to form the result

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, tokenize

I just began to work on XSLT. My input and expected output are as follows and the XSLT is also given below. I'm now facing 2 issues

1. As you could see I'm assigning the variable name dynamically and it throws the following exception
   `net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: Required item type of the context item for the attribute axis is node(); supplied value has item type xs:string`
2. When I set the variable name to some static string, I don't receive the exception but I don't see the expected output i.e. I'm wondering how do I map the tokenized strings

#### Input

```
<students>
  <field name="id">1,2,3</field>
  <field name="name">a,b,c</field>
 </students>
```

#### Expected Output

```
<students>
<student>
    <id>1</id>
    <name>a</name>
</student>
<student>
    <id>2</id>
    <name>b</name>
</student>
<student>
    <id>3</id>
    <name>c</name>
</student>
</students>
```

#### XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
            xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/" name="main">

    <xsl:for-each select="students/field">
        <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(.,',')">
            <xsl:element name="{@name}">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>                     
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure why the stylesheet you show uses XSLT 1.0 since you tagged the question with XSLT 2.0 and tokenize is a 2.0 function.

Also, your expected output contains a typo I think. Perhaps this is what you meant to write:

```
<student>
  <id>1</id>
  <name>a</name>
</student>
<student>
  <id>2</id>
  <name>b</name>
</student>
```

**Why you get an exception**

In XSLT, expressions depend heavily on the *context*. A line like the following:

```
<xsl:element name="{@name}">
```

depends on the context in the sense that it retrieves the value of the `name` attribute of either the current template match or the current item in an `xsl:for-each`.

In your case, the context is this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="tokenize(.,',')">
```

So, the context for `{@name}` is a tokenized string - that of course does not have any attributes.

**Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

   <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml"/>
   <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

   <xsl:template match="/students">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates/> 
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="field[@name='id']">
      <xsl:variable name="match" select="."/>
      <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(.,',')">
         <xsl:variable name="id-pos" select="position()"/>
         <student>
            <id>
               <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </id>
            <name>
               <xsl:value-of select="tokenize($match/following-sibling::field[@name='name'],',')[position() = $id-pos]"/>
            </name>
         </student>
      </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="text()"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<students>
   <student>
      <id>1</id>
      <name>a</name>
   </student>
   <student>
      <id>2</id>
      <name>b</name>
   </student>
   <student>
      <id>3</id>
      <name>c</name>
   </student>
</students>
```

Comment: Apologies Mathias Muller, that's my mistake. Corrected the typos. Thanks for sparing your time for reply. It worked charmingly :)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you don't know the number and names of the `field` elements then the following is more generic (and avoids tokenizing values multiple times):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="students">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:variable name="fields">
      <fields>
        <xsl:variable name="fields" select="field"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="field">
          <xsl:variable name="field" select="."/>
          <xsl:element name="{@name}s">
            <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(., ',')">
              <xsl:element name="{$field/@name}">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
              </xsl:element>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </fields>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:for-each select="$fields/fields/*[1]/*">
      <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"/>
      <student>
        <xsl:copy-of select="$fields/fields/*/*[$pos]"/>
      </student>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks Martin for your reply. I'll spend some time in understanding this.